# Turkey to Europe by car

Tags: europe, automobiles, turkey, istanbul

I'm looking to travel across Europe by car, like a crazy road trip with some friends. I'd like to start from Turkey. What is it like to drive from Turkey into Europe because that's where I would like to start the journey from.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. I'm not quite sure your question is [on-topic](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and it seems _really_ subjective. Can you please be more specific about your question? You can read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible, but right now it's really not sensible - due to the ongoing situation with refugees and illegal immigrants, many of the borders in the south-east of Europe are much more restricted than usual, and you'd have to go through migrant camps to get to them.

I'd recommend that you either wait for the current situation to stabilise, or choose a different route.

Comment: If starting from Turkey is the goal, he could go the long way through Caucasus countries and Russia. Or take a ferry between Turkey and Greece.

Comment: What is the source of your information?